# Using bibunits with TeXshop

Tags: texshop, bibunits

I am trying to run bibunits on TexShop based on the template that can be found in https://github.com/gsalzer/subfiles/tree/master/tests/bibunitsand

It is reproduced below with some minor modifications. The main file, all the chapters and bib files for each chapter are in the same folder.

The problem is that when running Cmd+Shft+L followed by Cmd+Shft+B I get the following error:

```
I found no \citation commands---while reading file main.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file main.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file main.aux
```

The only reason I am following this solution is because the github mentioned before seems very authoritative and it describes my situation: each chapter is a separate tex file and each chapter has a bibliography file.

The error happens irrespectively of me adding `% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk` in the first line of the main file or not. And btw, pdflatexmk.engire is in the Engine folder already. In addition, when I try to run bibtex (Cmd+Shft+B) on the aux files first, I get the exact same three errors.

It seems that the problem is that there are no citations inside of the main file, but why they should be? All the citations are inside of the chapters!

This is the type of problem that is usually solved with a simple instruction that nobody thought it was important and it was not mentioned in the 100+ tutorials and examples available online.

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{bibunits}
\defaultbibliographystyle{apalike}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\title{Main document}
\author{The Author}
\maketitle

This is a test for using \verb|bibtex| to generate bibliographies
chapter-wise with the \verb|bibunits| package.

\subfile{chapter1}


\end{document}
```

**chapter1.tex**

```
\documentclass[main]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\begin{bibunit}
\chapter{First chapter}

My references: \cite{A}

\putbib
\end{bibunit}
\end{document}
```

**bib1.bib**

```
@book{A,
    title={The meaning of A},
    author={A. Alpha},
    year=2019,
    publisher={Apublisher}
}
```

Comment: "This is the type of problem that is usually solved with a simple instruction that nobody thought it was important and it was not mentioned in the 100+ tutorials and examples available online." but is explained in the first section of the bibunit manual, run bibtex on the aux file of each chapter

Comment: @DavidCarlisle And how do you do that? When I hit Cmd+Sfht+B in the individual chapters I get the same error. No \citation, \bibdata or \bibstyles.

Comment: no idea how you would do  that from texshop. I would simply type `bibtex file1; bibtex file2` on the terminal command line

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If I run it from the command line I get the same 3 errors. I just did it your way. Thanks for your patience btw

Comment: your example stops at `! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \OPTIONS ` either delete or define `\OPTIONS`

Comment: `bibtex bu1;bibtex bu2` not `file1` also your example has no chapter2 and no bib file to test

Comment: @DavidCarlisle file2 was not listed for brevity and I have deleted the options.

Comment: the point of an example is to reproduce the problem and allow people to test answers, minimising it to make it easier to trace the code path is  useful, posting something that does not demonstrate the issue is less so. There is still no bib file so you still get errors from bibtex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the question has been edited to address all your additional concerns

Comment: I doubt that `bibunits` is compatible with the `subfiles` package (just a guess). Have you a version without `subfiles`?

Comment: @AlanMunn it's unnecessarily complicated, but does seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Using `subfiles` and `bibunits` together seems brave but seems to work.

You have not specified a bibliography, so `bibunits` seems to assume it is named after the main file.

after `pdflatex`  the file `bu1.aux` is

```
\bibstyle{apalike}
\citation{A}
\bibdata{main}
```

so your `.bib` file should be `main.bib`

`bibtex bu1`

runs without error producing `bu1.bbl`

so running
`pdflatex main`  twice produces

[image]